# counting with the right date c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0

I created an application which send email summary of service status and the total number of service. So the email must be send every 12 a.m. in each day for example to give a summary as shown in the queries. My problem, the queries are counting the services to include services that have done in previous dates! How do I alter the query to make it count for every day only i.e. Summary of counts for each date? Any help would be much appreciated!

```
   string ConnectionString = @"Data Source= (localdb)\Projects;Initial   Catalog=DataBasee; Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;";
            SqlDataReader reader;
            String SendMessage = @"Select (Select COUNT (*) FROM Service where Done = 3) As CountDone,
                                          (Select COUNT(*)  FROM Service where Undone = 5) As CountUndone";
            using (SqlConnection MyCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                //Open the connection string 
                MyCon.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SendMessage, MyCon);
                ArrayList EmailArray = new ArrayList();
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                var Email = new List<EmailSend>();
                //counter
                int CountDone = -1, CountUndone = -1;
                if (reader.Read())
                { 

                CountDone = (int)reader["CountDone"];
                CountUndone = (int)reader["CountUndone"];

                }
                int TotalDoneAndUndone = CountDone + CountUndone;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you should consider changing your query then like

```
Select 
(Select COUNT (*) FROM Service 
where Done = 3
and convert(date, your_datecolumn)  = CONVERT(date, getdate()) As CountDone,
(Select COUNT(*)  FROM Service 
where Undone = 5
and convert(date, your_datecolumn)  = CONVERT(date, getdate()) As CountUndone
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know in Oracle there is SYSDATE which will give today's date. Is it the same in SQL server ?

Comment: @user6440681, NO, in SQL Server it's `GETDATE()`. Did you tried the query in answer? Try it once and it should work fine.